# MultiValueDictKeyError at /accounts/upload_save/

Tags: python, html, django

I got an error,
MultiValueDictKeyError at /accounts/upload_save/
"'image'" .
I am making file upload system.It is that if i select file and put "SEND" button,selected image is sent to model.But now,when i select no image and put "SEND" button,the error happens.I wanna make a system that if i select no image and put "SEND" button,`<p>You should select at least one photo</p>` message is shown.

I wrote in photo.html

```
<div class="container" id="photoform">
          {% if form.errors  %}
        　<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        　<p>You should select at least one photo</p>
       　　</div>
     　　　{% endif %}

          <form action="/accounts/upload_save/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}

          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn" style="width: 30%;">
                  <span class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                    File Select1
                    <input type="file" name="image">
                  </span>
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>

          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn" style="width: 30%;">
                  <span class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                    File Select2
                    <input type="file" name="image2">
                  </span>
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>
          　　
          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn">
                  <span class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                    File Select3
                    <input type="file" name="image3">
                  </span>
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id" class="form-control">
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="form-control">
              </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

I wrote in views.py

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def upload_save(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            data.image = request.FILES['image']
            data.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = UserImageForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/photo.html', {'form': form})
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload_save/$', views.upload_save, name='upload_save'),
]
```

in forms.py

```
   class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ImageAndUser
            fields = ('image',)
```

in models.py

```
class ImageAndUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", verbose_name="imageforegin")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True,)

    date = models.IntegerField(max_length=100,null=True)
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens because I wrote if-else statement and I worte print(form.errors) in else statement .What should I do to fix this?How can I write it ?

Comment: Your `UserImageForm` looks like it doesn't validate that your `image` field is   present... so `request.FILES['image']` is failing... So fix that and it's probably worth adding a `required` to your input form to aid in the client not sending the form with an empty image to start with.

Comment: @JonClements thx ur comments.I read ur message,but I cannot understand how to write it.Could u write your intended codes in answer?

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include your `UserImageForm` - someone might be able to help

Comment: @JonClements I added forms.py

Comment: Thanks - can you also show how you've defined `image` in the `ImageAndUser` model?

Comment: @JonClements I added models.py too

Comment: Try putting `image = forms.ImageField()` in your form and that should make it required and validate it - the rest of your code should then just work...

Comment: @JonClements Did u mean 'image = forms.ImageField()'  to UserImageForm of forms.py?I added the codes so,but same error happens...What should I do?

Comment: You have only one imagefield in your forms.py . but in your form.html you try to upload lots of images? am I right?

Comment: @ytsejam in my system,users can upload 1~3 pictures

Comment: @user8504021 where are the fields for orher images?

Comment: @ytsejam I only have this filed.Am I wrong to it?

Comment: @user8504021 I mean in your form.py you have image, image2, image3 fields but inside your model you dont have them.

Comment: @ytsejam Is it related to the error?I think it cause different error

Comment: can you paste your full error on a site dpaste.de for example ?

Comment: I will write you an answer . I think changing your forms.py will solve your situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = ImageAndUser
        fields = ('image',)
```

and change your views.py

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def upload_save(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            data.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            data.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = UserImageForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/photo.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: This is a way to make the `image` a required form field. Alternative is to override `__init__` in your form and set `self.fields['image'].required = True`.